# OOMScoreAdjust in .service files is ignored?

Tags: linux, debian, memory, services, out-of-memory

We're struggling with `mysql` being killed by OOMKiller since upgrading from Debian 9 to Debian 11.

I see that several `.service` files have `OOMScoreAdjust=###` defined, but they don't seem to be honored, and `choom` tells me the score adjust values for these services are `0`.

The value is also ignored for other services besides `mysql`, like `netdata` but seems to be honored for `systemd`, which defaults to an adjust value of `-1000`.

Is specifying `OOMScoreAdjust` in `.service` files no longer valid in Debian 11? I would guess that's not it, because `systemd`'s score is correctly read by `choom`. So is something else going on?

Besides `choom` telling me the adjust score is `0`, the process continues to be killed, which makes me quite certain that the value is not being honored, but I don't know why that is.

I'm not sure if this issue is specific to Debian or what, since I don't have enough information, nor do I know where to look next.

Comment: If you look at the value of /proc/pidnumber/oom_score_adj for mysql, what does it say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I had not nested `OOMScoreAdjust` under the `[Service]` heading, and so it was not applied. That explains why it worked for some processes (ones where the value was properly nested under `[Service]`,) but not others.

Values set by `choom` don't appear to persist across reboots.